# How do you deploy a kubernetes cluster on separate nodes using only yaml on google cloud

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

Goal: have a yaml deployment that I simply run `kubectl create -f deployment.yaml` on and it create nodes with pods spread accross them in the manner I describe in the yaml file.

Goal output. 3 nodes on google cloud with 2 nodes with 2 pods front-end/back-end and a 3rd node with the database running with a persistent volume.

There is no way to test this locally since docker-desktop is a single node system. Google cloud initially put all my pods on one node and they did not schedule because of lack of resources.

So I looked up the docs and asked several slack channels. The consensus is to use pod/node affinity and antiAffinity to make sure the pods I want are on the nodes I want.

[Client Application github](https://github.com/marcusjwhelan/docker_js_stack_client)

[API/DB application github](https://github.com/marcusjwhelan/docker_js_stack_api)

[Project overhead, k8s+Kustomize](https://github.com/marcusjwhelan/docker_js_stack)

Here are the github repos I am testing this with and trying to build what I am describing. I am trying to stay as cloud agnostic as possibly but if I need to be more specific with cloud keywords please leave a comment about it. The whole deployment is spread between the /kubernetes directory in each project. They did work locally before I added the pod/node affinity items.

Comment: I think you’re talking about deploying your own app, not K8s itself, right?

Comment: you can't create nodes that way on GKE. You need to create the nodes through the GKE control plane.

Comment: I think they were attempting to deploy a custom cluster on GCP. And then deploy an application on top of it. All with one command.

This can be done with a combination of Ansible, Terraform, Kubeadm, and Kustomize. See my answer below for more information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking for here is [Kubeadm](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/). It's a tool used to bootstrap Kubernetes masters and join new nodes to clusters. [Here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kubelet/) is a reference document and [here](https://godoc.org/k8s.io/kubelet/config/v1beta1#KubeletConfiguration) are the API docs for [Kubelet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kubelet/) and all of its arguments. Using Kubeadm and these arguments, you can build an [initConfiguration](https://godoc.org/k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/apis/kubeadm#InitConfiguration), [clusterConfiguration](https://godoc.org/k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/apis/kubeadm#ClusterConfiguration), and [nodeConfiguration](https://godoc.org/k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/apis/kubeadm#JoinConfiguration).

1) After you create these three files, put `initConfiguration` and `clusterConfiguration` into a single YAML file. And put `nodeConfiguration` into its own file. Put the first file on your master(s) and the second file on your node(s). If you're installing with a Multi-Master configuration, keep [this document](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/high-availability/) in mind when building your configurations. You will also need a [load balancer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/high-availability/#create-load-balancer-for-kube-apiserver), [proxy](http://dockerlabs.collabnix.com/kubernetes/beginners/Install-and-configure-a-multi-master-Kubernetes-cluster-with-kubeadm.html), or clever [DNS trickery](https://github.com/coredns/coredns/tree/master/plugin/loadbalance) to enable this.

2) [Install the following packages](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/install-kubeadm/):

```
docker
containerd
kubelet
kubeadm
```

3) [Disable any Swap partitions, SELinux,](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/install-kubeadm/#before-you-begin) and [configure your firewall](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/install-kubeadm/#check-required-ports) appropriately.

3) [Bootstrap Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/setup-tools/kubeadm/kubeadm-init/) on your Master(s) with your config file: `kubeadm init --config /tmp/master.yml`.

4) [Add your workers nodes to the cluster](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/setup-tools/kubeadm/kubeadm-join/) with your config file: `kubeadm join --config /tmp/node.yml`.

5) Install a [network plugin](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/#pod-network).

6) Deploy the rest of your software using a [Kustomize](https://kustomize.io/) project. Hell, you could even [manage your Kubeadm configuration files with Kustomize](https://blog.scottlowe.org/2019/10/16/using-kustomize-with-kubeadm-configuration-files/). I have. You could even throw the network plugin manifest in here.

This Kubernetes solution is fully cloud agnostic and all of Kubernetes is automated but the configuration isn't. I would automate steps 1-5 with something like [Ansible](https://www.ansible.com/). Where you would declare each step as a task or role in a playbook. It supports a [ton of modules](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/list_of_all_modules.html). And there are open source roles on [Galaxy](https://galaxy.ansible.com/) when there aren't.

That leaves your infrastructure. Making this cloud agnostic is impossible. No two vendors have the same API. That's why abstraction layers like Kubernetes exist to begin with. To solve this problem, attempt to be *Cloud Aware* instead. Use a tool like [Terraform](https://www.terraform.io/) to manage your infrastructure for you. Then, [add your required Terraform commands to your Ansible playbook](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/terraform_module.html).

Bam, now you can deploy your entire infrastructure, configuration, and application with a single command. From a *single* YAML file:

`ansible-playbook -i inventory.ini site.yml`

Well, a *single* YAML file and a bunch of other [roles](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html) and [templates](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/template_module.html), [playbooks](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks.html), and [Terraform configuration files](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/index.html). ;)

EDIT: Here are some open source projects I've written that leverage these ideas and design principles. You should be able to at least gleam a lot of Ansible logic from them. The first is meant to build a single node cluster on a bare metal server. The latter is meant to build a four node cluster on Proxmox.

- [Bare_Metal_Kubeadm](https://github.com/zimmertr/Bare_Metal_Kubeadm)
- [Bootstrap-Kubernetes-With-QEMU](https://github.com/zimmertr/Bootstrap-Kubernetes-with-QEMU)

Both work fully with all of the manifests I have written [here](https://github.com/zimmertr/Kubernetes-Manifests). Which should also provide you with a wealth of Kustomize and Ansible examples.

Comment: Wouldn't Terraform just replace all the kubeadm stuff, also could you replace ansible with CircleCI, for tag release commands to simple build the app on a build push? Or a update to the project when there is a master push to a github hook?

Comment: It's a philosophical discussion whether or not you think Terraform should manage configuration and infrastructure or just infrastructure. My view of the ecosystem suggests the latter is more popular. However, I have entertained putting all of the necessary commands into the userdata section of a cloud-init script and just using Terraform. 

And using a CI/CD platform (I prefer Argo/Gitlab) would definitely improve upon this. But if you look at the original question, their goal was to completely build their app and infra in a single command. Which Ansible effectively provides.